# Handling OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2::CallbackError in OmniAuth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, omniauth

How can I handle the error:

```
OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2::CallbackError
```

...generated by OmniAuth when a user goes through to the Facebook login, but decides to cancel?

I have seen a few threads about this, but none of the solutions worked for me.

I tried placing this:

```
OmniAuth.config.on_failure = UsersController.action(:oauth_failure)
```

...into the `omniauth.rb` initializer file with no success.

I am using the **omniauth-facebook** gem with **Rails 4.0.2**.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Many thanks!
Michael.

My gemfile.lock file reveals the following gems related to the omniauth-facebook gem:

```
oauth2 (0.8.1)
  faraday (~> 0.8)
  httpauth (~> 0.1)
  jwt (~> 0.1.4)
  multi_json (~> 1.0)
  rack (~> 1.2)
omniauth (1.1.4)
  hashie (>= 1.2, < 3)
  rack
omniauth-facebook (1.5.1)
  omniauth-oauth2 (~> 1.1.0)
omniauth-oauth2 (1.1.1)
  oauth2 (~> 0.8.0)
  omniauth (~> 1.0)
```

Comment: What is your omniauth-oauth2 version? Check your Gemfile.lock.

Comment: Ashitika - I have updated my question with the relevant section of the gemfile.lock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I upgraded the `omniauth-facebook` gem to version **1.0.6** and now it is working as expected.

For anyone else coming across this issue and would like to capture this error, here's what you need:

**/config/initializers/omniauth.rb**

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do

    provider :facebook, 'xxx', 'xxx', scope: "email,publish_stream,user_location,user_birthday"

end
```

**/config/initializers/omniauth_failure_callback.rb**

```
OmniAuth.config.on_failure = Proc.new do |env|

    UsersController.action(:omniauth_failure).call(env)

end
```

**/app/controllers/users_controller.rb**

```
def omniauth_failure

    flash[:danger] = "Unable to connect with Facebook at this time."
    redirect_to root_url

end
```